# elegant and efficient linq solultion to count number of episodes

Tags: c#, linq

I have several classes like this:

```
public class TvShow
{
    public Title {get; set;}
    public List<Season> Seasons {get; set;}
}

public class Season
{
    public int SeasonNumber {get; set;}
    public List<Episode> Episodes {get; set;}
}

public class Episode
{
    public int EpisodeNumber {get; set;}
}
```

I have a list of TvShows, I want to get the total episode count over all seasons of all TvShows in an efficient manner. Obviously there is the foreach solutions:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var show in tvShows) {
    foreach (var season in show.Seasons {
        foreach (var episode in season.Episodes {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

anything more elegant or faster I can do with linq?

Comment: You know exposing List<Season> like that could leave you in a big hole?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson how so?

Comment: Anyone using the instance can change the list to a new a one. Might not be a problem, but what would some git doing myTvShow.Seasons = nil? do to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your code is equivalent to:

```
int count = tvShows.SelectMany(show => show.Seasons)
                   .SelectMany(season => season.Episodes)
                   .Count();
```

Or you could use `Sum` to find out how many episodes are in each show, and then again to find out the total number of episodes across all shows:

```
int count = tvShows.Sum(show => show.Seasons.Sum(season => season.Episodes.Count));
```

Or a sort of mixture, just summing the episode count of all seasons in all shows:

```
int count = tvShows.SelectMany(show => show.Seasons)
                   .Sum(season => season.Episodes.Count);
```

I'd expect the last to be the most efficient - but really, unless you've got an awful lot of shows, I'd expect all options to be very fast. The last is also pretty elegant though, so that's what I'd go for.

Comment: Is it more efficient than the foreach senario?

Comment: Can you go straight from Show to Episodes like that?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: Have added a little about that. I doubt that it matters.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, as human as the rest of us!  I'd deleted my comment after I saw the edit.  No one will ever know... ;)

Comment: Just out of interest, why would you expect a mix to be fastest?

Comment: @Rawling: No need to iterate as many times as the first, but fewer `Sum` operations than the second. But hey, I could be wrong. I doubt that it will make any significant difference unless there are many, *many* episodes...

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
tvShows.SelectMany(show => show.Seasons)
       .Sum(season => season.Episodes.Count)
```